# Remote connection IP to use

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-connection

I have two laptops that both run on ubuntu and installed ssh server and ssh client on them. One is usually on my desk at home and one I usually bring to my company. When I'm at home I can easily ssh to one from the other by typing this command (to login to the other laptop whose IP address is: 192.168.0.105) :

```
ssh -p 22 myusername@192.168.0.107
```

However, When I'm at my company, I try to type the same command and ofcourse it doesn't work. I understand that when at home I'm on LAN network, that my laptops actually using my ISP's address which differ from 192.168.0.107 asummed 203.113.131.1. So could you tell me what IP that ssh shoud use for my laptop (at work) to connet to my computer at home?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**[port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)**

This will be a job for [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router at home.

You will need to redirect inbound traffic on your home router on a certain port (say 2022) to your home laptop on port 22.

Then you will be able to connect to your router on 203.113.131.1:**2022** and it will be forwarded to your home laptop (192.168.0.107:**22**).

---

**Static IP**

Setting up a static IP on your home laptop will make sure that you will not get a new IP address and break the above awrup.